# Animating Text/Graphics in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, arcgis-10.3, animation

ArcScene includes the capacity to animate 3D text added to the scene, through the use of Graphics Layers. I'm able to use this to make text fade in and out as visibility of layers is changed, however I'd like to achieve something similar in ArcMap.

I've got a clunky work around which involves creating new point layers with transparent symbology, labeling them to suit the different layers, and fading those in with the relevant layer. I can't apply the labels to the layers I'm displaying as they are all raster. Is there a more straight forward way to achieve this?

I could do this in ArcScene with a view point set perpendicular to the plane of the data, but I'd rather use ArcMap because it is more stable with the amount of raster data I'm using.

Comment: ArcScene uses the video card dynamically but ArcMap uses static caches to render... you would need to switch ArcMap into dynamic mode - only available in ArcObjects. Is ArcObjects an option?

Comment: it's an option if it will allow me to animate text and graphics as part of a broader animation of the data view

Comment: Have a read of http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_dynamic_display_works/0001000003wt000000/ for the fundamentals of IDynamicDisplay then create a dynamic glyph using IDynamicGlyphFactory. See sample Dynamic Logo http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/00010000006z000000.htm

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I think not much more than a copy/paste of your two comments will be required to provide an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @MichaelMiles-Stimson:

> Have a read of
>   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_dynamic_display_works/0001000003wt000000/
>   for the fundamentals of IDynamicDisplay then create a dynamic glyph
>   using IDynamicGlyphFactory. See sample Dynamic Logo
>   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/00010000006z000000.htm